# Best client server protection

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, anti-virus, clients

I have around 80 laptops connected to Active Directory server.(Windows Server 2008 r2). Currently all the laptops have Avast free antivirus on them.
Is there any way I can check for unprotected laptops through active directory.

Answer (score 1):

You will most likely need a "business" or "professional" version of an anti-virus product that has a management feature available.  Some products are managed in the cloud while others require the management software be installed on a machine on the LAN.  Most if not all are capable of pulling client info from AD, and the same is true concerning scanning the LAN for unprotected clients.

As for recommendations of AV software, that's more of an opinion based question.  Those don't seem to be received well on SE.  In any case, I personally use ESET products. IMHO their AV client is the best on the market, BUT their management software has got to be some of the most difficult to configure and to actually get it to communicate with the Windows OS can be a frustrating experience.  To be fair, I think that may apply across the board with the stand-alone management of AV clients though.